# plotly multiple plot facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

I'd like to do multi plots with two axes on each plot like this

```
library(plotly)
ay <- list(
  tickfont = list(color = "green"),
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right", title = "y2 axis title"
)


par(mfrow=c(2,1))
ax <-list(title = "x axis title")
ay1 <-list(title = "y1 axds title")
plot_ly(x = 1:3, y = 10*(1:3), name = "slope of 10") %>%
  add_trace(x = 2:4, y = 1:3, name = "slope of 1", yaxis = "y2") %>%
  layout(title = "Double Y Axis", yaxis2 = ay, xaxis = ax, yaxis = ay1) 


 ax <-list(title = "x axis title")
 ay1 <-list(title = "y1 axds title")
 plot_ly(x = 1:3, y = 10*(1:3), name = "slope of 10") %>%
   add_trace(x = 2:4, y = 1:3, name = "slope of 1", yaxis = "y2") %>%
   layout(title = "Double Y Axis", yaxis2 = ay, xaxis = ax, yaxis = ay1)
```

but when you run that code you still only see one plot. Can `plotly` do multi plots? Can it do faceting with two axes?

Comment: Are you trying to plot these 2 (same) plots on the same page?

Comment: yes. I'd like them to show up one above the other. But Ideally I'd like to be able to use facet_wrap with plotly. is that possible?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55251470/missing-data-when-supplying-a-dual-axis-multiple-traces-to-subplot

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `subplot`. Check this [page](https://plot.ly/r/subplots/) for more

```
library(plotly)
ay <- list(
    tickfont = list(color = "green"),
    overlaying = "y",
    side = "right", title = "y2 axis title"
)

ax <-list(title = "x axis title")
ay1 <-list(title = "y1 axds title")   

 subplot(
        plot_ly(x = 1:3, y = 10*(1:3), name = "slope of 10") %>%
            add_trace(x = 2:4, y = 1:3, name = "slope of 1", yaxis = "y2") %>%
            layout(title = "Double Y Axis", yaxis2 = ay, xaxis = ax, yaxis = ay1), 
        plot_ly(x = 1:3, y = 10*(1:3), name = "slope of 10") %>%
            add_trace(x = 2:4, y = 1:3, name = "slope of 1", yaxis = "y2") %>%
            layout(title = "Double Y Axis", yaxis2 = ay, xaxis = ax, yaxis = ay1), nrows = 2)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: when I run the above code the plot does not appear. I also removed the ")" after "ay1" in the last line

Comment: I posted the output I get when I run the exact same code. I am using `plotly_3.6.0`  and `ggplot2_2.1.0`

Comment: Try this: assign your first `plot_ly` graph to `a`, and the second to `b`. Then run `subplot(a,b, nrow= 2)`. Does the plot show up now?

Comment: @user3022875, are you checking in the Viewer Pane? `plotly` plots won't show up in the Plots pane